# Unauthorized response in tests after migrating to Spring 6 SecurityFilterChain

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm migrating an app to Spring 6. The following code cannot be used anymore, given the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class was deprecated:

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
}
```

So, as explained in Spring's documentation, I replaced it with the following code:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                 .httpBasic().disable()
                 .csrf().disable()
                 .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                 .and().build();
    }
}
```

After doing so, all of my integration tests started to fail, due to **Unauthorized** responses from the API. If I run the application and do the same request with cURL, everything works as expected. If the deprecated SecurityConfig is present, the tests works just fine.

What is it that I'm missing?

I created a simple PoC to reproduce the issue:

- Controller:

```java
@RestController
public class SampleController {

    @GetMapping(path = "greet")
    public ResponseEntity<Pojo> greet(@RequestParam(value = "who") String who) {
        final Pojo response = new Pojo(format("Hi %s!", who));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }
}
```

- Model:

```java
public class Pojo {

    private String who;

    public Pojo(String who) {
        this.who = who;
    }

    // ... GETTER & SETTER
}
```

- Test:

```java
@WebMvcTest(SampleController.class)
class SampleControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void testSyncController() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/greet").param("who", "John"))
                .andExpect(status().is(200))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.who", equalTo("Hi John!")));
    }
}
```

- Gradle build config:

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.18'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'


group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config'
    implementation 'com.h2database:h2:2.2.224'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

configurations {
    compileClasspath {
        resolutionStrategy.activateDependencyLocking()
    }
    runtimeClasspath {
        resolutionStrategy.activateDependencyLocking()
    }
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

The test fails with the following log:

```
15:54:47.463 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
15:54:47.473 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating BootstrapContext using constructor [public org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultBootstrapContext(java.lang.Class,org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate)]
15:54:47.507 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper for test class [org.example.SampleControllerTest] from class [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper]
15:54:47.515 [Test worker] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [org.example.SampleControllerTest], using SpringBootContextLoader
15:54:47.518 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [org.example.SampleControllerTest]: class path resource [org/example/SampleControllerTest-context.xml] does not exist
15:54:47.518 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [org.example.SampleControllerTest]: class path resource [org/example/SampleControllerTestContext.groovy] does not exist
15:54:47.518 [Test worker] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [org.example.SampleControllerTest]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
15:54:47.519 [Test worker] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils - Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [org.example.SampleControllerTest]: SampleControllerTest does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
15:54:47.570 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.ActiveProfilesUtils - Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [org.example.SampleControllerTest]
15:54:47.606 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider - Identified candidate component class: file [/<redacted>/test-spring6/build/classes/java/main/org/example/SampleApplication.class]
15:54:47.616 [Test worker] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Found @SpringBootConfiguration org.example.SampleApplication for test class org.example.SampleControllerTest
15:54:47.619 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [org.example.SampleControllerTest]: using defaults.
15:54:47.619 [Test worker] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.webservices.client.MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener]
15:54:47.626 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper - Skipping candidate TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener] due to a missing dependency. Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes and their required dependencies available. Offending class: [org/springframework/transaction/TransactionDefinition]
15:54:47.626 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper - Skipping candidate TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener] due to a missing dependency. Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes and their required dependencies available. Offending class: [org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAttribute]
15:54:47.627 [Test worker] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@21526f6c, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@49f5c307, org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener@299266e2, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@5471388b, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@66ea1466, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@1601e47, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener@3bffddff, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener@66971f6b, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener@50687efb, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener@517bd097, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener@142eef62, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.webservices.client.MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener@4a9cc6cb, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@5990e6c5]
15:54:47.629 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - Before test class: context [DefaultTestContext@32057e6 testClass = SampleControllerTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@26be6ca7 testClass = SampleControllerTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class org.example.SampleApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@62163b39, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@207b8649, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@bf39837b, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@17e0e1a5, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@13e3c1c7, [ImportsContextCustomizer@6ea1bcdc key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.MessageSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hateoas.HypermediaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.reactive.WebTestClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.servlet.OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcSecurityConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebDriverAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jsonb.JsonbAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.freemarker.FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.servlet.OAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.groovy.template.GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mustache.MustacheAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@366ef90e, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@a5b0b86, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@0], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].
15:54:47.638 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener - Performing dependency injection for test context [[DefaultTestContext@32057e6 testClass = SampleControllerTest, testInstance = org.example.SampleControllerTest@2e5c7f0b, testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@26be6ca7 testClass = SampleControllerTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class org.example.SampleApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@62163b39, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@207b8649, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@bf39837b, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@17e0e1a5, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@13e3c1c7, [ImportsContextCustomizer@6ea1bcdc key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.MessageSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hateoas.HypermediaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.reactive.WebTestClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.servlet.OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcSecurityConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebDriverAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jsonb.JsonbAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.freemarker.FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.servlet.OAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.groovy.template.GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mustache.MustacheAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@366ef90e, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@a5b0b86, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@0], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener.recordApplicationEvents' -> false]]].

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::               (v2.7.18)

2024-01-10 15:54:47.910  INFO 96732 --- [    Test worker] org.example.SampleControllerTest         : Starting SampleControllerTest using Java 17.0.9 on <redacted>)
2024-01-10 15:54:47.911  INFO 96732 --- [    Test worker] org.example.SampleControllerTest         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-01-10 15:54:48.828  WARN 96732 --- [    Test worker] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration : 

Using generated security password: <redacted>

This generated password is for development use only. Your security configuration must be updated before running your application in production.

2024-01-10 15:54:49.019  INFO 96732 --- [    Test worker] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@58eac00e, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@6acffb2d, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@6b321262, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@713a35c5, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@5ef85555, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@79a13920, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@2b6c7012, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@2c0c4c0a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@61149fa5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@6d6bff89, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@357bc488, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@4ea17147, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@149c39b, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@5707f613, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@519c6fcc, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@674da77b]
2024-01-10 15:54:49.071  INFO 96732 --- [    Test worker] o.s.b.t.m.w.SpringBootMockServletContext : Initializing Spring TestDispatcherServlet ''
2024-01-10 15:54:49.071  INFO 96732 --- [    Test worker] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : Initializing Servlet ''
2024-01-10 15:54:49.072  INFO 96732 --- [    Test worker] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2024-01-10 15:54:49.096  INFO 96732 --- [    Test worker] org.example.SampleControllerTest         : Started SampleControllerTest in 1.436 seconds (JVM running for 2.349)

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /greet
       Parameters = {who=[John]}
          Headers = []
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST=DefaultSavedRequest [http://localhost/greet]}

Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 401
    Error message = Unauthorized
          Headers = [WWW-Authenticate:"Basic realm="Realm"", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

Response status expected:<200> but was:<401>
Expected :200
Actual   :401
```

Again, if I keep the old SecurityConfig, the test works properly. I already tried some suggestions from similar questions, such as adding:

```java
http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
    .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD).permitAll()
```

to the `http` builder, but the error persists.

Comment: Maybe consider using the `spring-boot-starter-security` dependency for getting the Spring security stuff?

Comment: can you share the link to the sample POC? and also by looking onto the error, seems it is looking Basic `Authorization` header, as you mentioned through curl it's working, can you share the curl request as well

Comment: @dan1stiscrying makes no difference: adds no new libs, and also does not work.

Comment: @kcsurapaneni thanks for your input.
- Code provided should suffice to create a MRE, as it contains nothing else to what was shown apart from a standard Spring main class.
- cURL is just a simple: curl "localhost:8080/greet?who=john"